# Book about magic rocks, fire and guardian magics

Tags: story-identification

A few years ago I read a book with a young boy as the main character. In this book everybody had magic stones, the boy's stone was small, just a pebble really, he used it for fire magic, and eventually it was broken.

He finds evil shadows lurking in the alleyways of the city, he gets attacked by one which freezes him and gives him hypothermia and he gets saved by an old wizard who becomes his advisor and friend. He goes on some sort of quest to save the sentient during magic of his city, and witnesses a new sinister magic being born that later tries to destroy the magic of his city.

The boy finds a new rock. I remember it was the size of a baby's head, but it was hard for him to use since it wasn't technically his. He saves his city and the two magics protect different sections of the city. The book had a title that was related to fire and the cover was also fiery.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Did the book seem targeted to children? Adolescents? Teenagers? Adults?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/181006/book-where-a-pickpocket-steals-a-sorcerers-stone-and-becomes-his-apprentice

Answer (score 2):

A partial match would be *[The Magic Thief](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheMagicThief)* by Sarah Prineas

> The Magic Thief follows Connwaer, a young pickpocket in the city of Wellmet, who makes the mistake of stealing a "locus magicalicus", a stone that holds a wizard’s power. Touching a wizard’s locus stone is an almost-certain death sentence, but Conn somehow manages to survive. Curiosity convinces Nevery, the owner of the stone Conn tries to steal and recently returned to the city after a decades-long exile, to take Conn in as a servant, though Conn thinks he’s going to be the wizard’s apprentice. Nevery has been allowed to return to Wellmet in an effort to help stem the leak that seems to be draining the city’s magic. Conn seems to know more about it than anyone gives him credit for, but will he be able to convince anyone in time to save the city’s magic?

It has magic stones, a young boy apprenticed to an older wizard, and a scheme to destroy the magic of the city. However, the order of plot operations doesn't quite match in that he doesn't get his *locus* until after he's apprenticed, and I haven't found any mention of fire magic being his thing.